# Change Sound Settings via Registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry, control-panel

I often switch between using my headset and speakers on my computer depending on what I am doing and it is a bit annoying going through all the dialogs. Is it possible to write a script to simply switch between devices?

Answer (score 0):

Those are only 5 clicks, for example, on Windows 7:

1. Right click the audio icon.
2. Click *Playback Devices*.
3. Click your audio device.
4. Click Set Default.
5. Click OK or press <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

For automation purposes, use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). We can't write this for you... :-)

Comment: (1) Five clicks is a lot; especially when done frequently. (2) They never said it was 7. (3) They may not even have the audio icon in the tray. (4) Yes you/we *can* write a script for them, it’s been done plenty of times here. (5) This “answer” to the question is/does not. (It is not an answer, it is a **response**, eg, a *comment*.)